# Is there a way to get just the free space on a drive?

Tags: powershell, drive

I want to be able to get the free space on a disk as an integer, preferably in either bytes or kilobytes as an integer. I haven't been able to find a way to do this. My end goal is to create a while loop to copy a file until the disk space is full.

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but why do you want to do this? Why would you want to fill the disk space? The only reasons I can think of are unethical such as for a malware. I'm just concerned that by answering this I might cause harm. So could you please let me know why so I can feel better about helping?

Comment: I'm planning to store a large number of mp4 files on my computer and I want to know how many I can fit on it. I created a dummy mp4 file with the weight of the average of all the mp4 files on my cloud drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PS C:\> (Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).SizeRemaining

97864130560
```

That will output a `UInt64` value as a number of bytes remaining free on your C:\ drive.

If you want to get this information for a different volume, use the `Get-Volume` function to find out which drive letter you are looking for:

```
PS C:\> Get-Volume

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
                         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      84.1 MB    602 MB
C                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     91.14 GB 231.67 GB
            Recovery     NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                       515 MB    529 MB
E                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     86.96 GB 231.67 GB

PS C:\> (Get-Volume -DriveLetter E).SizeRemaining

96593814487
```

You can convert that value to different storage sizes:

```
# Replace 1MB with 1KB or 1GB or 1TB
PS C:\> (Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).SizeRemaining/1MB

93313.09765625
```

Note: MB is the notation for 1 Megabyte (1,000 bytes) but Windows is actually counting in Mebibytes MiB (1,024 bytes), so my C drive has 93,313 MiB free -- not 93,313 MB. I just looked this up and was intrigued to read the History and Usage section of this Wikipedia article about the Mebibyte, which mentions that Windows actually reports these values incorrectly (I tested it today, this is still the case): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
get-psdrive c
psdrive c
psdrive c | % free
```